# Parsing string in Python

Tags: python, string

I have python string s that contains data structured in this way:

```
INFO: some text...
INFO: some text...
INFO: some text...
INFO: some text...
223A
```

I need to extract just number 223 from whole string and put it in another integer variable. How would I do that?

Comment: Hi, what have you tried yourself? Is the number always at the begging of a row followed by the letter A?

Comment: Hi, I only know splitting string into two parts. I don't have yet an idea how to do this. Number is alaway at the beggining of a row, followed by any upper case letter.

Answer (score 2):

You can use that to eliminate non-numeric characters from a string

```
import re
re.sub("[^0-9]", "", string_to_be_parsed)
```